# Unable to change app language at runtime on Xamarin Forms -> Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a crossplatform app using Xamarin Forms, primary target Android.
The app I'm working on refers to `.resx` files for languages.
The translations works fine as the phone is set to different langauges.

How can I switch languages from the app settings at runtime on the fly?

I tried using `DependencyService` to call a function on Android side, but, despite returning with no error, it doesn't change the language.

C# project

```
bool test = DependencyService.Get<ILanguageService>().SetLanguage(selectedLang.StringValue);
```

Android Project

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LanguageService))]
namespace MyLangApp.Droid.Service
{
    public class LanguageService:ILanguageService
    {
        public bool SetLanguage(string lang = "")
        {
            try
            {
                Locale locale = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang) ? new Locale("en-US") : new Locale(lang);
                Locale.Default = locale;
                var config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration();
                config.Locale = locale;
                var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CurrentCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1)
and [CurrentUiCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=netcore-3.1).

As far as I remember, you can set them at runtime.

Comment: Should that work on Xamarin Forms/Android? I tried but doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I think I managed to do it like this once: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");`

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that you are using *i18n* with a **MarkupExtension**. If so, then you can dynamically change the culture inside the `Translate` extension class' ctor.

```cs
namespace ResxLocalize
{
    [ContentProperty("Text")]
    public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        private readonly CultureInfo ci;
        private const string ResourceId = "MyApp.Resources.R";

        public TranslateExtension()
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS || Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                // SET YOUR CULTURE HERE
                ci = new CultureInfo("DESIRED CULTURE");
            }
        }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            string translation = string.Empty;

            if (Text != null)
            {
                ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(ResourceId, typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

                translation = manager.GetString(Text, ci) ?? Text;
            }

            return translation;
        }
    }
}
```

Every time a string is being obtained, a new ctor is being fired and the culture is being retrieved dynamically. You can change the CultureInfo inside the ctor here:
`ci = new CultureInfo("DESIRED CULTURE");`

You can see an example using App properties [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/290527/#Comment_290527)